# specific context of てもらう

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, context

In this sentence, I am unsure what てもらった is referencing, as the parts that follow make me unsure of what it is trying to convey. If it helps, I have added the past and following sentence to make more sense of the context.

> 「もしあなたにもっとマシな案があるなら聞かせて。あたしが考えるの、飽きてきたところなの」
>
> かなり喋ってもらったが、どうでもいいことばかりじゃないか。俺はまず当然の疑問を口にすることにした。
>
> 「あのさ…それって本物の銃？」

From what I have gathered, I feel as though the てもらった sentence is something along the lines of 'I was made to speak a fair amount, but it doesn't bother me. Firstly I must make my reasonable concerns known'

I am uncertain as some of the words in the sentence such as かなりmust have some ambiguity to them, so I might be missing out on something.

Comment: One hint might be that the subject of 喋る is the あたし, not 俺.

Comment: So going by that, its something along the lines of "I have been making her speak alot"

Comment: Right. And you'd need to add nuance of もらう.

Comment: "she's been speaking at me alot, but it doesn't bother me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This かなり喋ってもらった is just "She talked quite a lot (for the sake of me)" (or super-literally, "I received a favor of talking quite a lot"). This is a fairly simple example of [(-て)もらう](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86-te-morau-%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-te-moraitai-meaning/), so you may need to review its basic usage. By もらう, he is (at least superficially) thanking for her long talk. かなり is an adverb that means "fairly", "quite a lot", etc.

> かなり喋ってもらったが、どうでもいいことばかりじゃないか。
>
> She talked quite a lot (for me), but they're all unimportant things, aren't they?

Or you may translate this sarcastically like "Thank you for the long speech about all the things that don't matter".